# Is there a way to "get-clipboard" and use the referenced clipboard info in a command line?

Tags: powershell, scripting, macros

I'm making a script to convert a PDF to txt file.
I'm trying to copy a file name and then use the copied file name in the next line of the script. But using get-clipboard doesn't include that data in the same command line. Is there a way to essentially ctrl+v it in that line using PS?

```
PS C:\Users\PiRho> @(get-childitem C:\Users\PiRho\Desktop\PDF_Convert -name) [0] | set-clipboard
PS C:\Users\PiRho> cd C:\Users\PiRho\Desktop\PDF_Convert
PS C:\Users\PiRho\Desktop\PDF_Convert> .\pdftotext -table | get-clipboard
  I/O Error: Couldn't open file 'get-clipboard'
```

So this is the old way I was doing it.

```
PS C:\Users\PiRho> @(get-childitem C:\Users\PiRho\Desktop\PDF_Convert -name)[0] | set-clipboard
PS C:\Users\PiRho> cd C:\Users\PiRho\Desktop\PDF_Convert
PS C:\Users\PiRho\Desktop\PDF_Convert> .\pdftotext -table #Ctrl+V#
```

The `#Ctrl+V#` is done using my macro, but it will sometimes use the previous clipboard info.

Effectively I'm looking for a replacement `Ctrl+V` in powershell that doesn't rely on a macro to put the file name there.

Comment: Does it have to be the clipboard? the best way is to save the filename to a variable and use that.

Comment: @HAL9256 That is kind of what I was thinking but I'm very new to PS and any kind of coding in general. That being said, Im unsure how I would go about doing that.

Comment: Your command `.\pdftotext -table | get-clipboard` doesn't make sense to me, a `Get-` cmdlet is a source not a destination for a pipe. what you could try: `.\pdftotext -table (get-clipboard)` or `.\pdftotext -table (get-clipboard)[0]`

Comment: Or `.\pdftotext -table (gci Desktop\PDF_Convert)[0].Name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way is to use [Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_variables?view=powershell-6) so something like:

```
$File = @(get-childitem C:\Users\PiRho\Desktop\PDF_Convert -name)[0]
cd C:\Users\PiRho\Desktop\PDF_Convert
.\pdftotext -table $File.FullName
```